# Is this passive sentence correct

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Is this passive sentence correct?

> I hope you find this article as interesting, as writing it was to me!

If not, how can I rephrase it to sound correct?

Comment: *I hope you find this article as interesting to read as it was for me to write.*

Comment: Perfect thanks. Can you post it as an answer so that I can makr it as answer and close this question

Comment: I can't see anything passive about your sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiom

> X as Y ... as Z

requires that Y and Z be comparable characteristics of X. In your sentence X=*this article*, Y=*interesting*, an Z=*writing*.  But the last two aren't comparable, and you're in danger of your reader expecting something like

> I hope you find this article as **interesting** as I found it **irritating**!

This is clearly not what you mean. As a stylistic consideration, it helps if the syntax in both parts is parallel. In your version, the person who finds the article interesting is the subject (i.e., *you*), but the person doing the writing is the object of the preposition *to* (i.e., *me*).

Both syntax an style may be accommodated by

> I hope you find this article as interesting to read as it was for me to write.

Comment: awesome. this is such a great explanation. Can you suggest any online tools/services (not grammarly) that can help me proof read and suggest corrections. do you provide proof reading services?

Comment: You might try englishforums.com. Also this answer: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7571/where-can-i-ask-for-free-proofreading